# S3 event notification for when the object lock expires

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am looking at AWS S3 lock feature. I need to receive an S3 event when the set retention period expires. The lifecycle events are the closest one that I could find. But this doesn't trigger when the retention period expires (in both Governance or Compliance mode)

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't an event for this case. Could you write an item to DyanmoDB with a TTL of the expiry? Then listen to delete on the table stream. It's more to manage, but it'll work around there not being an event.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like a good workaround with little additional overhead. I will use it in the worst case. But would like to know from experts like you if S3 itself has any event trigger on lock expiry.